# Run Android 1.x 2.x,3.x and 4.0 on Android Studio's emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run a device with Android 1.x, 2.x, 3.x and 4.0 on Android Studio, it gives me this error: The emulator process for AVD (AVD name) has terminated.

I tried another versions of Android Studio or AVD Manager but it also didn't work, the only thing that worked was Android 1.6 emulator with 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: I don't think Android Studio still contains images for Android 1 2 or 3, they are all discontinued. What ancient Android Studio Installation do you use?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.2, the oldest Android Studio that you can download on Android Developer.

Comment: Why do you want this?  1.x was released on I think 1 phone ever, the Moto G.  3.x was tablet only, for some truly ancient tablets-  phones continued on 2.x until the two reconverged with 4.0.  And nothing has been released on those OSes for a decade.

Comment: I have found these lines on idea.log : D:\MV\Android\.android\avd\Nexus_One_API_5.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Nexus_One_API_5, D:\MV\Android\.android\avd\Nexus_One_API_5.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Nexus_One_API_5 and Unable to determine if Nexus_One_API_5 is online, assuming it's not.

Comment: I think its something with ARM EABI.